# r - nth occurrence in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with two columns (FirstName and State).

```
my.df = data.frame(FirstName = c('John', 'Paul', 'John', 'Sarah', 'Haley', 'Paul', 'John'),
                   State = c('VIC', 'NSW', 'VIC', 'QLD', 'TAS', 'NSW', 'VIC'))

FirstName State
   John   VIC
   Paul   NSW
   John   VIC
  Sarah   QLD
  Haley   TAS
   Paul   NSW
   John   VIC
```

I would like to include an additional column that lists the nth occurance for each value in the FirstName column.  For example, 'John' appears in rows 1, 3 and 6 - the new column would therefore list '1' in row 1, '2' in row 3 (as this is the second time 'John' is listed) and '3' in row 6 (as this is the third time 'John' is listed).

My desired outcome would appear as follows:

```
FirstName State Index
   John   VIC     1
   Paul   NSW     1
   John   VIC     2
  Sarah   QLD     1
  Haley   TAS     1
   Paul   NSW     2
   John   VIC     3
```

Any assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or if you're feeling `dplyr`-ishly loopless:

```
new.df <- my.df %>% 
   group_by(FirstName) %>% 
   mutate(Index=1:n())
```

Or you can just use `row_number()`

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my.df)[, Index := seq_len(.N), by = FirstName]
```

Or just base R

```
with(my.df, ave(seq(FirstName), FirstName, FUN = function(x) seq(length(x))))
```

Comment: No I'm not 'kidding you'. I just didn't know about `row_number`. Maybe feign a little friendliness, unless that's what passes for friendly over here.

Comment: And I was just doing the same myself...

Answer (score 0):

Something quick and dirty...

```
my.df = data.frame(FirstName = c('John', 'Paul', 'John', 'Sarah', 'Haley', 'Paul', 'John'),
                   State = c('VIC', 'NSW', 'VIC', 'QLD', 'TAS', 'NSW', 'VIC'))

my.df$Index = 0
for(i in 1:nrow(my.df)){
  nameinds = which(my.df$FirstName==my.df$FirstName[i])
  my.df$Index[nameinds] = 1:length(nameinds)
}

print(my.df)
```